# Laravel pusher broadcast does not work when i change APP_URL in the env file

Tags: echo, broadcast, pusher, laravel-7

when I use this it works :

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

but with this it does not :

```
APP_URL=http://helpme.test
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?
Is that URL accessible from the broadcasting server?

Comment: @doydoy I get a Broadcasting exception, and the URL is not accessible from the broadcasting server because its in my local machine and im using pusher api